# bash - queue subshells

Tags: bash, shell

```
function _abc {
:
1 min task
:
_check &
}

function _check {
wait for the previous calls of _check to complete
:
15 mins task
:
}
```

function abc loops depending on number of tasks. It is imperative that _check is backgrounded because function abc needs to keep on working and not wait for function check to complete

So basically, what I need is for the function check to be running one at a time and not all together. That is, the remaining calls of function check should be queued up and run one at a time once the previous one finishes.

Comment: Look into the use of `wait` which will block until any backgrounded children have terminated.

Comment: wait would be better but cant have it in function abc because i need it to keep on running also cant have it in check because how can it know the pid of the previous check

Comment: You can know the PID of the last backgrounded process, as it is stored in `$!`.  You can also `wait` for a specific process to end with `wait $PID` (or, in this case, `wait $!`.)

Comment: @BrendenCarvalho pass the last `_check`'s PID as an argument to `_check`. If no argument is given, start `_check` directly, or `wait` accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Go's idea of channels](https://gobyexample.com/channels) can be used here:

```
mkfifo my_pipe
exec 3<>my_pipe
trap 'rm my_pipe' EXIT
printf a >&3
function _abc {
    ...
    _check &
}

function _check {
    until read -N1 -u3; do :; done
    ...
    printf a >&3
}
```

Essentially:

1. Create a named pipe for communicating between instances of `_abc` and `_check`.
2. Have `_check` block on a read from the pipe (one byte in the example).
3. Start off the first `_check` by printing a character (doesn't matter which) to the pipe. This should perhaps done outside the function if it loops.
4. Have each `_check` instance write back to the pipe on exit.

To avoid writes to the pipe blocking, I added the pipe as an open file descriptor the shell (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164295/70524). Also, if multiple `read`s are queued up on the same pipe, and one of the succeeds leaving the pipe empty, the others will report EOF. To overcome this, we have to loop on `read` until it succeeds in reading.

Comment: If you're not cleaning up `my_pipe`, this will fail on any subsequent executions; I would add a `trap 'rm my_pipe' EXIT` to this.

Comment: @DopeGhoti thanks for the suggestion, added it.

Comment: this is awesome :)

Comment: `read` has a built-in timeout, but you'd need to know the theoretical maximum runtime so that you don't have a false timeout, causing a desync.

Comment: The idea of channels doesn't really translate. The more I think of it, the more holes I see in this. :/

Comment: @DopeGhoti suggesting a swap of the usages of `echo` and `read`?

Comment: This is the first time I think I've seen a named pipe used bidirectionally.  In theory, it should work, but, if you'll forgive the metaphor, pipes are easy to clog when you do this.

Comment: @muru How does this work? Does read remove 'a' from the pipe?

Comment: @BrendenCarvalho yes. `read` will block until there's something to read, and because of `-n1`, it will only read a single character.

Comment: But then 'a' is present in the pipe always its never deleted. So read will always work

Comment: @BrendenCarvalho Eh? What do you imagine happens when `read` reads a character? It puts it back in?

Comment: @muru Here is my script for some reason it isn't working. The checking function runs only once  http://pastebin.com/HWtc51Xe

Comment: Your script creates subshells of subshells and doesn't wait for all of them to end. If you `echo` something at the end of `_checkupload`, you'll see it output after 10 seconds, for each instance of `_checkupload` you started, even if the script ended. If you remove one layer of backgrounding, you can just add a `wait` at the end: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14874545/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35272/discussion-between-brenden-carvalho-and-muru).